# How to delete a blank row that is based on a cell value in other column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have column a and b. i want to delete the blanks in column b that is based on a value in column a.

Here is the code that i tried but it is not working.

```
Sub Delete()

Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long

  With Sheets("Sheet2")
 .Select

 Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
 Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

   For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

      If .Cells(Lrow, "A").Value = "Administration" And _
         .Cells(Lrow, "B").Value = "" Then .Rows(Lrow).Delete

   Next Lrow

 End With
End Sub
```

Here is the data that i am using:

[image: Column A and B]

Comment: The code looks good. What is the error you see? I think you cannot use "Delete" as the name of sub procedure?

Comment: i dont encounter any error it is just not working and i dont know why.. hmm wait i try to change the Sub name

Comment: @henrywongkk i tried to change the name to getDel. but it is still not working..

Comment: If it does nothing at all (no errors), then it means that your condition `.Cells(Lrow, "A").Value = "Administration" And .Cells(Lrow, "B").Value = ""` is never true. That means that there might be extra spaces somewhere in your cells that you don't see. Try `Trim$(.Cells(Lrow, "A").Value) = "Administration" And  Trim$(.Cells(Lrow, "B")).Value = ""` the `Trim$` function removes any spaces in the beginning or end of your cell values before checking.

Comment: Check the length of the values in those cells if that doesn't do the job already. Even linebreaks or tabs or non-breaking spaces can sit in those cells. And something trivial as working of the wrong sheet?

Comment: If you don´t need to check A column, as per your description (not as per your code) try `Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete` or `Range("B"&.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row&":A"&.UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Hi @DavidGarcíaBodego sorry for my grammar. but im trying to delete a row which is column a = administration and also in a column b that is equal to blank. i tried your code Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete but it deletes entire row which is just equal to blank even if it is not equal to administration

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego i also tried you Range("B"&.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row&":A"&.UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete but im getting an error "object doesnt support this property or method"

Comment: @coder The code you showed looks good and should do what you describe. The issue seems to be your data. Make sure A contains really `Adminitsrator` no line breaks no spaces! And make sure B is really empty, no spaces no line breaks. Then run your code again and I'm pretty sure it will work. I tested it and for me it worked and deleted the desired data.

Comment: hi @JvdV i try to equal it to length. like this one:
 
"If .Cells(Lrow, "A").Value="Administration" And _
Len(.Cells(Lrow, "B").Value) = 0 Then .Rows(Lrow).Delete" but it is still not working.

Comment: @coder also please check the values of `Lastrow` and `Firstrow` maybe they were detected incorrectly! Tell us both values please.

Comment: @coder: What I meant is that you go outside your if statement and just check that these cells are empty. You might want to use `Debug.Print Len(.Cells(Lrow, "B").Value)`, put a break on that line and hit F5 untill you reach `Lrow 6` and pay close attention to the immidiate window.